# User can type text in input and upload it(make the text stay) on site

Tags: javascript, php, html

what I want is people can add cards. cards are a simple preview about what the article(recipe article) is about. so I to give user possibility to change **3** card not more(cuz of spams).
so I had a simple idea to make to buttons like so :

[image: the design of buttons]

just like you saw I want the edit or view or whatever display='block' a input and you can write in the input,. after submit the text gets added (or get replaced) with the text of card
and that means they can add cards(when a card added it automatically gets in page and gets it position); and of curse it should be visible for others.
and last thing my idea for adding images to top of the card is it should be a input that user can paste the URL of image in there; and for the number problem(that this image should be for that card) I want to add two buttons for every card so this is the idea of design:

[image]

How should this be done. I know its little complicated but I would really really appreciating if you can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+user+can+update+site+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please read: Are [“how would I get started?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad/308836#308836) 
questions too broad? (tl/dr: "yes")

Comment: Also please leave profanity at the door